# Will a database call return before a trigger completes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net

If I save to a table that has a trigger, and I call a stored procedure in my ASP.NET MVC application using Entity framework, will my db call be blocked and only return until the trigger has completed?

Or is it possible my code will continue executing to the next line of code and the trigger may complete later?

Answer (score 0):

Triggers run within the transaction of the calling DML statements.  Everything will be blocked until they return.

If you need something to run async, then you could have the trigger just write a quick message to the broker and then run a long running process that way instead of having your web call block.